# Iterating Through a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, loops

I have a json file  which look like this:

```
{
  "records": {
    "Dates": [
      "05-Aug-2021",
    ],
    "data": [
      {{
    "strikePrice": 15550,
    "expiryDate": "05-Aug-2021",
    "PE": {
      "strikePrice": 15550,
      "expiryDate": "05-Aug-2021",
      "underlying": "NIFTY",
      "identifier": "OPTIDXNIFTY05-08-2021PE15550.00",
      "openInterest": 15113,
      "changeinOpenInterest": -4644,
      "pchangeinOpenInterest": -23.50559295439591,
      "totalTradedVolume": 140006,
      
    },
    "CE": {
      "strikePrice": 15550,
      "expiryDate": "05-Aug-2021",
      "underlying": "NIFTY",
      "identifier": "OPTIDXNIFTY05-08-2021CE15550.00",
      "openInterest": 630,
      "changeinOpenInterest": -89,
      "pchangeinOpenInterest": -12.378303198887343,
      "totalTradedVolume": 364,
    
    }
  }
```

To iterate though this file if i do this :

```
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

I get:

```
records
filtered
```

From here how do i get the keys in `data` which has to correspond to the `Dates`. The examples i found did not have multiple levels and this is complex.

Comment: It is a dictionary and your loops iterates only along the keys (of ```data```). try with ```data.iteritems()``` and make a case study: the variable of iteration is a dictionary, a list, ...? then perform the corresponding action

Comment: the brackets are unbalanced

Comment: Lucky you, at that strike you're ITM with today's bump. Also, that's not _actually_ the JSON you're working with, as [it's invalid](https://jsonlint.com/). Lastly, what do you actually want to do with this data? I don't think simply iterate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to iterate over the data:

```
for price in data["records"]["data"]:
       print(price)
```

This will give you the list-elements in the `data`-key.

These list-elements are themselves dictionaries, hence you can check their keys to other values:

```
if price["expiryDate"] == "05-Aug-2021"
```